# Angular-jQCloud: Resize words based on number of words

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using the [angular directive](https://github.com/mistic100/angular-jqcloud) for [jqcloud](http://mistic100.github.io/jQCloud/index.html):

```
<jqcloud words="project.words" auto-resize="true" delay="10" steps="7" font-size="{from:0.06, to:0.04}" style="width:100%; height: 250px;"></jqcloud>
```

I want to be able to change the font-size based on the number of words as it is given a different word-set based on which page the user is on. The word-set is created as part of angularjs promise.

I tried `font-size="project.wordSize"` and passing it a string of `{from:0.06, to: 0.04}` (with different numbers depending on the size) however, this didn't work. I assume because as `project.wordSize` is part of a promise, it isn't available when the element is created and therefore fontSize will equal null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up modifying the jqcloud.js source code with the following code:

```
drawWordCloud: function() {
  ...

  // Generate font sizes
  this.data.sizes = [];

  if (this.sizeGenerator) {

     // apply a multipler depending on the number of words
     var multiplier = 1.1;

     if(this.word_array.length < 5){
         multiplier = 2.1;
     }
     else if(this.word_array.length < 10){
        multiplier = 2;
     }
     else if(this.word_array.length < 20){
         multiplier = 1.2;
     }
  }

   for (i=0; i<this.options.steps; i++) {
     this.data.sizes.push((this.sizeGenerator(this.options.width, this.options.height, i+1)).replace('px', '') * multiplier + 'px');
   }

  ...
}
```

Not the best but a quick solution.